# Time series: Vector AR(I)MA models with exogenous variables

Tags: time-series, arima, multivariate-analysis, armax

I have taken a course based on the book "Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting" by Peter J. Brockwell and Richard A. Davis.
I have learned about vector ARMA models, vector VAR models and Whittle's algorithm.
I am interested in methods that employ exogenous variables in the univariate and multivariate cases.
I can find mention of vector ARMAX models (with various names ARMAX/ARIMAX, XARMA/XARIMA, exogenous ARMA etc.) online and many packages that can model and predict these time series but I cannot find resource that explains the mathematics involved.
Can anyone recommend a resource to learn how these models and the algorithms work?

Answer (score 0):

Helmut Lütkepohl "New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis" 2005

https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-540-27752-1